# can't change the sshd's prot in CoreOS

Tags: ssh, port, coreos

System release: CoreOS 2135.5.0
Kernel: 4.19.50-coreos-r1
System install way: vmware

When I change the port in the `sshd.service`，it displays:

```
CoreOS-234 ssh # echo "Port 10000" >> /usr/share/ssh/sshd_config ;systemctl mask sshd.socket;systemctl enable sshd.service;systemctl restart  sshd.service

-bash: /usr/share/ssh/sshd_config: Read-only file system
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In coreos /usr is designed to be a read-only file system, Remounting /usr is theoretically feasible, but is not officially recommended**

[You can refer to this](https://coreos.com/os/docs/latest/customizing-sshd.html)

**I use the following command to solve this problem**

```
sudo sed -i '$a\Port=60022' /etc/ssh/sshd_config && \
sudo systemctl mask sshd.socket && \
sudo systemctl enable sshd.service && \
sudo systemctl start sshd.service
```

Answer (score 0):

The file system that you are working in is currently in Read-only mode. Remounting the file system to read-write should resolve the issue. You will need to have root privilages:

```
$ mount -o remount,rw /
```

Occasionally the reason your file system will be running in read-only mode is due to Kernel issues, therefore there may be further problems with the system that will need to be debugged. Regarding the Kernel errors you may want to have a look at the following link: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/436483/is-remounting-from-read-only-to-read-write-potentially-dangerous?rq=1